# How to remove __MACOSX and .DS_Store from zip files in the whole directory mac

Tags: terminal, mac, zip

I need to create a script that searches and removes __MACOSX and .DS_Store from zip files in the whole system (MACOS).

I have found this useful command that does the job but only if you are already in the directory of the file:

```
for f in *.zip; do zip -d "$f" "__MACOSX*"; done
```

I need to implement the search command and combine it with this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We’re not a script writing service, but we can assist with specific questions.  Also, searching the *whole* system is counter productive, since users aren’t going to be writing to system protected volumes.  Can you start off with an edit detailing what directories you’d like to search?

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for your quick reply and my apology. I think you kind of solved my problem as I assume that the starting directory would be "Users" and that includes all the sub-directories within.

Comment: Do not forget to include a "@" before the name of the person you're replying to to have them notified :) (e.g. @someone will have the user named "someone" get notified for this comment).

Comment: This stack exchange link may help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924236/mac-zip-compress-without-macosx-folder/13665552#13665552